# Compute this once, not twice

Tags: functions, evaluation

I have two questions.

So, I have a function `g` defined in terms of another function, `f`:

> `g[z_] := Product[f[z][[i]], { i, 1, Length [f[z] ] }];`

My problem is that `f[z_]` takes a while to compute.

**Question 1:** When I call `g`, does it compute `f` twice?

**Question 2:** If so, is there a way to make it not do that?

**Note:** I simplified my code a little bit. `g` is actually defined in terms of two parameters, so I cannot generate a table of `f` and have it call the parts of the table.

Comment: `g[z_]:=Times@@f[z]`

Comment: You cannot have a pattern object (e.g., `z_`) on the RHS of a function definition except in a rule. To avoid multiple evaluations use a `Module`, eg., `g[z_] := Module[{ft = f[z]}, ...]`

Comment: @BobHanlon sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: ciao gives a good example of how one can more simply write what you have shown in your answer, and it is thus likely more efficient—however, it all comes down to your f[z] definition. Are you using `SetDelayed` ( i.e., `:=` ) or `Set` ( i.e., `=` )? In either case, you can use *memoization* to remember the values you have calculated for some `f[z]`. This looks something like: `...=f[z]=...` where, before the `...=`, you have either `Set` or `SetDelayed` and `f[z_]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BobHanlon gives a good answer for 2.
For question 1, Here's an easy way to test. Define f[z_] using Echo and have it return a known result. Then evaluate g[z].

```
In[1]:= f[z_]:=(Echo@"f[z] was called";{1,2,3});
In[2]:= g[z_]:=Product[f[z][[i]],{i,1,Length[f[z]]}];
In[3]:= g[1]
```

```
>>f[z] was called
>>f[z] was called
>>f[z] was called
f[z] was called
Out[3]= 6
```

Comment: This is a neat way to profile, but couldn’t one also just use `Trace`?

Comment: Sure, but Trace is not always easy to follow. Echo is simple.

Comment: valid point. I don’t know my way around `Echo` & `Trace` is easy to apply after function definition occurs, rather than needing to insert it into the definition. Wood screw versus a machine screw maybe ;)